# MobileSubstrate - checking which bundle an object is in

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I'm making a MobileSubstrate plug-in which is supposed to:
a) hook instance methods of a specific class/classes and
b) do different things depending on the bundle ID of the application containing the object (which is an UIResponder subclass, to be specific).

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: if it's a plugin and running in some application's context, do you get your application ID when you call to [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], and if not, what identifier do you get?

Comment: This method always returns com.apple.springboard...

Comment: Then your tweak only modifies SpringBoard. Modify your filter to "com.apple.UIKIT" rather then "com.apple.springboard".

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a try and let you know the results.

Comment: And it worked! Thank yo very much! Can you please post it as an answer in order to let me accept it?

Comment: @H2CO3 posted it with a bit more info below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said calling [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] always returns com.apple.springboard and only that. Which means your code is only running inside SpringBoard.

MobileSubstrate tweaks are only injected into some, not all, processes. You control this via it's filter (loaded from a .plist file).

If you want to have your code inject itself into all instances of the class then modify your filter to "com.apple.UIKit" rather then "com.apple.springboard" all apps will now your code.

Comment: Typo: If I recall correctly, bundle identifiers are case sensitive, therefore, `com.apple.UIKit`.

Comment: Matoe, thanks. I checked with some of my existing code and yes it is spelt like that. The reason I checked is there is some inconsistency with regard to which bundle id's apple does and doesn't capitalise, and in this case I misremembered.